# Rails Routes - How to add a route of an object without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created an object named settings. So i also provided its route in the routes.rb file i wrote "map.resources :settings". Now as i'm trying to save to the database with that object, it keeps on getting to the localhost:3000/settings url, which i don't have. i', also having this error

NameError in SettingsController#create

uninitialized constant SettingsController

PLEASE HELP! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure, but I believe you need to have a controller to add a route.  Check out this diagram: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:mvc

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails, you have to stick to its rules. Rails implements the MVC pattern, where the controller has the role to provide the linking between a request started in the client web page (view) to creating, reading, updating and deleting (CRUD) objects (== models). The `routes.rb` define here the mapping from the URL to controller actions, not directly to the resources. See the ["Rails Guides for Routing"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.

If you want to use your model objects, Rails provides an easy way to start that: [scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding). By using `rails generate scaffold setting <attr_name1>:<type1> ...`, you are able to create the following:

- A migration for the database that creates the `settings` table.
- Generation of the model object `Setting` that maps to the created database table.
- A controller `SettingsController` that allows CRUD for your model objects.
- View files for the actions generated for the controller.

You can all do that by hand, but it is a good starting point to begin with. And read the basic tutorials and play with the example applications to get a feeling for Rails ...